# scrapyd service and periodic scraping in virtualenv

Tags: python, ubuntu, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

First time I installed **scrapyd** in Ubuntu 14.04, I didn't use the generic way.

Using **apt-get**, my **scrapyd** was considered a service that can be started and have (log/config/dbs...) dependencies however the **scrapy** version was very outdated.

So I installed **scrapyd** with **pip** in **virtualenv**.
Although it is up to date, I can't start **scrapyd** as a service and I can't find any dependencies.
Where do I create the Configuration file to link (eggs/dbs/items/log) dependencies ?

I have more than 10 spiders. Using a remote Ubuntu server, I want each spider to scrape periodically (once a weak for example) and send the data into **mangodb**. Most of the spiders don't have to scrape simultaneously.

What is the **best approach** to run **scrapyd** as a **service** and run its spiders **periodically** in my **Ubuntu server**?

Comment: Not sure I get your question or not... but you can run `scrapyd` in background ... and then schedule your spider in Cron like this  `curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=somespider`

Comment: run scrapyd as a background task (i have found screen to be useful) with a supervisor (supervisord)